# Form submitted but getInstance() returns false

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using [2amigos file upload widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget) in my app. \
My view file looks like:

```
<fieldset class="form-control-sm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="patient-file" class="file col-md-4 control-label">Profil şəkili</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->widget(\dosamigos\fileinput\BootstrapFileInput::className(), [
                'options' => [
//                        'name' => 'file',
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => false,
                ],
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'previewFileType' => 'image',
                    'showUpload' => false,
                    'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary-outline',
                    'removeClass' => 'btn btn-danger-outline',
                    'removeIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> '
                ]
            ])->label(false); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In my controller action I wrote:

```
if (UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file')) {
    echo "yes";
    // do my staff...
    exit;
} else {
    echo "no";
    // confused. why no ?
    exit;
}
```

I'm confused that, why image's not uploading; why getInstance() returns false?

What's I'm doing wrong?

p.s I read [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33632590) before posting $this.
p.s.s Other field values posting correctly and working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use you have passed

```
['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
```

as options in your `$form = ActiveForm::begin();`

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#creating-forms